# Teams Bot - get credentials from Key Vault

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

I have searched a bit but didn't found something which is helping me. I created a bot for teams and like described in all examples I am using the appsettings.json to store the ID and the password for the bot (MicrosoftAppId and MicrosoftAppPassword). These are both handled by the framework somehow. But now I want to use an Azure Key Vault to store the secret instead of having the appsettings file.

So I found some examples explaining how to do this in BotFramework V3 with BotAuthentication  Attribute and even something for BotFramework V4 [here](https://github.com/microsoft/botframework-sdk/issues/5268) ([working link for the linked example here](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/0fff9476addd6bdd7ee2f0c1146da5f03b140d67/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/13.basic-bot/Startup.cs)). But even that example is old and does not exist anymore like that.

How am I supposed to do this for a teams bot and c# dotnet 3.1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following method to store the secret value

> ```
>         var storageSecretValue = keyVaultClient.GetSecretAsync($"{this.configuration.GetSection("KeyVault")["BaseURL"]}{this.configuration["KeyVaultStrings:StorageConnection"]}");
> ```

please refer the following sample document to more clarification:-
https://github.com/OfficeDev/microsoft-teams-apps-newemployeeonboarding/blob/main/Source/Microsoft.Teams.Apps.NewHireOnboarding/Startup.cs

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/azure-samples/key-vault-dotnet-core-quickstart/get-started-keyvault-net/