Where to store credentials in Teamsbot?
Currently developing a Teams bot using the teamstoolkit in node js. The bot needs to talk to an API that uses basic authentication. Obviously I dont want to store credentials in plain text or code, so I would like to use environment variables. But what happens to these environment variables when I upload the bot to azure? or zip it and upload it directly to teams?
What is the best way to store these credentials.
is it even possible to store them in a secure way?

We can store appsettings values in KeyVault and read it at runtime. You can implement Azure KeyVault. Please refer - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/security/fundamentals/key-management, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/general/overview#why-use-azure-key-vault, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/general/tutorial-net-create-vault-azure-web-app, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70567008/teams-bot-get-credentials-from-key-vault

If you are using Azure app service, you can store these variables in app service's environments. You can either update the environment variables of your appservice in Azure portal or modify the bicep files in Teams Toolkit project. Then you can use process.env.{your variable} in your code.
If you need more secure way to store these variables, on recommendation is using Azure key vault.

Could you explain more about the bicep files? I can't seem to get it to work.

You can modify the environment variables in "appsettings" in your webapp. You can find it in "infra/azure.bicep".
